# Entropy and equilibrium concepts at astronomic scales

Tags: gravity, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics, entropy, equilibrium

I am always puzzled to read here and there discussions dealing with thermodynamic concepts applied to astronomic scales where gravity matters. To my opinion, there is a certain carelessness to go into such arguments, since the gravitational energy is long-range. As such, a basic principle on which the laws of statistical physics and thermodynamic rely, namely the short range of interaction, is no longer true.
Why then these kind of discussions are not discarded from the start ? I would say, the systems where gravity matters are out-of-equilibrium, period. Our solar system, where gravity converts mass to light, which bathes our earth and allowed life to grow, is a prominent example.

Comment: A place to start might be the classic textbook by Tolman, "Relativity, Thermodynamics and Cosmology".

Comment: Wouldn't that make thermodynamics in/on the Earth problematic as well, since there's gravity here as well? (The Earth's atmosphere has vertical density, pressure, and temperature gradients, due to the Earth's gravity -- would that mean that we can't use thermodynamic concepts for the Earth's atmosphere?)

Comment: You should cite a work that applies thermodynamics to astrophysical systems. Otherwise the question is ill defined for an answer.

Comment: The concept of Entropy and Equilibrium are more fundamental than the forces that are involved within and out of the system. Statistical Mechanics is just that-a formulation based on making statistical predictions about the system, and you just need to base the forces that are involved to make those predictions.